How can I determine which Google account is linked to a specific installed Android app?
I have several Google accounts logged into my phone. As mentioned on How can I change which Google account I use to pay for a subscription via Play?, each installed application is linked to a Google account. How can I know which one?
Assume that the application doesn't sell anything via Google Play (otherwise the Google account could be seen before making the payment).

Possible dupe? How Do I Know Which Google Account is Used for the Market?

@AndrewT. thanks, different as here we assume that the application doesn't sell anything via Google Play (otherwise the Google account could be seen before making the payment).

Hmm, I guess I read the question differently. I thought it's about account used for the installation, not for the in-app registration...

I have this issue with Games, when I change phones.  I have been just deleting the app, changing to the desired account and reinstalling it.
Otherwise, this is the only thing I have discovered. This will give you a list of the apps that are linked to the selected account.

Open a browser (its easier on a desktop)
Go to myaccount.google.com
Click on Security
Scroll down to "Your connections  to third party apps and services"
Click on "See all connections"


